# alter the request payload in WSO2

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2. 
I have proxied a service. Now i am trying to alter the input request content. The backend is expecting a request like below

```
 <input>
 <newParam>    
 {
    "id" :"8888822"   
 }
 </newParam>
 </input>
```

But the frontend will be sending the request as below:

```
 {
    "id" :"8888822"   
 }
```

without the starting and ending tags.

Any documents or links which will help me do this would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the Payload Factory mediator[1]. In the following sample, you just retrieve the value for the "id" field from the request body and attach it to your predefined payload.

```
    <log level="custom">
      <property name="IncomingMessage" expression="$body" />
   </log>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
             <input>
             <newParam>    
             $1
             </newParam>
             </input>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="fn:concat('{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;', //id/text(), '&quot;}')" />
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <log level="custom">
      <property name="TransformedMessage" expression="$body" />
   </log>
```

You will see the `IncomingMessage` and the `TransformedMessage` in the `wso2carbon.log`.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator

Comment: Hi  Chamila, Thank you very much for the reply. This is helping me move ahead. I applied the payload factory mediator but i am just checking if i can see the incoming input content and how it is transformed after applying the policy, in trace or logs, because I do not see it in server.log

Comment: Edited the answer to include log messages. Hope this helps.